# How to speed up custom non-destructive groupby aggregation?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I wrote the following custom aggregation that merges simultaneous measurements into as few as possible datapoints without deleting any values

```py
def aggregate_nondestructive(df: Series | DataFrame) -> Series | DataFrame:
    """Aggregate multiple simulataneous measurements in a non-destructive way.
    
    Given a DataFrame of size m×k, 
    this will construct a new DataFrame of size m'×k, where m' = max(df.notna().sum()) is the 
    maximal number of measured not-null valuesin a column.
    
    Example
    -------

                              Acetate  Base   DOT  Fluo_GFP   Glucose  OD600  Probe_Volume    pH
        measurement_time                                                                        
        2020-12-09 09:48:38      <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      <NA>  4.578233   <NA>          <NA>  <NA>
        2020-12-09 09:48:38      <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      <NA>      <NA>  0.445          <NA>  <NA>
        2020-12-09 09:48:38  0.116585  <NA>  <NA>      <NA>      <NA>   <NA>          <NA>  <NA>
        2020-12-09 09:48:38  0.114842  <NA>  <NA>      <NA>      <NA>   <NA>          <NA>  <NA>
        2020-12-09 09:48:38      <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      <NA>      <NA>  0.485          <NA>  <NA>
        2020-12-09 09:48:38      <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      <NA>      <NA>   <NA>           200  <NA>
        2020-12-09 09:48:38      <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    1112.5      <NA>   <NA>          <NA>  <NA>
        2020-12-09 09:48:38      <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     912.5      <NA>   <NA>          <NA>  <NA>
        2020-12-09 09:48:38      <NA>  <NA>  <NA>      <NA>  4.554859   <NA>          <NA>  <NA>
        
    Returns
    
                              Acetate  Base   DOT  Fluo_GFP   Glucose  OD600  Probe_Volume    pH
        measurement_time                                                                        
        2020-12-09 09:48:38  0.116585  <NA>  <NA>    1112.5  4.578233  0.445           200  <NA>
        2020-12-09 09:48:38  0.114842  <NA>  <NA>     912.5  4.554859  0.485          <NA>  <NA>    
    """
    if isinstance(df, Series):
        return df

    mask = df.notna()
    nitems = mask.sum()
    nrows = nitems.max()
    result = DataFrame(index=df.index[:nrows], columns=df.columns).astype(df.dtypes)
    
    for col in result:
        result[col].iloc[:nitems[col]] = df.loc[mask[col], col]
    return result
```

I want to use this to aggregate simultaneous measurements in a table with ~1M rows (using `groupby(["measurement_time"]).apply(aggregate_nondestructive)`), However, it is very, very slow. Any simple ideas how to speed this up aside from rewriting it in numba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `stack` the data to remove the `nan`. Use `groupby.cumcount` to get the number of non null value per column for each measurement_time. Append this to the index of the `stack` data and then `unstack` on the level that are the original column names. Then `reindex` the columns to be sure to get all original columns (this might not be necessary if you have at least one value in each column across all the measurement_time) and `reset_index` that was appended from the `cumcount`.

```
_tmp_df = df.stack().to_frame(name='val')
res = (
    _tmp_df
      .set_index(_tmp_df.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount(), append=True)
      ['val'].unstack(level=1)
      .reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
      .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
)
print(res)
#                       Acetate  Base  DOT  Fluo_GFP   Glucose  OD600  \
# measurement_time                                                      
# 2020-12-09 09:48:38  0.116585   NaN  NaN    1112.5  4.578233  0.445   
# 2020-12-09 09:48:38  0.114842   NaN  NaN     912.5  4.554859  0.485   

#                      Probe_Volume  pH  
# measurement_time                       
# 2020-12-09 09:48:38         200.0 NaN  
# 2020-12-09 09:48:38           NaN NaN
```

Note: this is not a groupby aggregation, it can perform the operation on the whole dataframe at once

Comment: Oh, this seems to work decently well, although the typical problem with `stack` happened of flipping all data types to `float64`. (`Probe_Volume` was `Int32` and the rest was `Float32` in this example)

Comment: @Hyperplane good point, I don't have this problem as all data is float64 the way I built the dataframe. I would say you can chain with `.astype(df.dtypes)` at the end